# Outlook Reminders Happening Too Soon

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, reminder

In Outlook 2003, I flag an item (of type 'Post', which automatically saves back to my Inbox (the Post was created from a Mail item in the Inbox)) with a reminder for later in the day but as soon as I've closed the item the reminder dialog pops up (giving me default option to snooze for 5 minutes).

Anyone know why it's doing this and how I can change it so that the reminder will only pop up at the time I've actually set the reminder for?

Answer (score 0):

On Outlook, it has an option to set your desired timezone, which can be different from the timezone you set for System.

Please check the option under Outlook->Options->Calendar->Timezone.
And confirm it is the same as your System timezone (Control Panel->Date and Time->Timezone).